# Need help reading Android Stacktrace for Mvvmcross fragment crash

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

On the Google Play Dashboard I've a large amount of Crashes and ANR's. They have the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x00028>
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x000db>
at Android.App.Activity.OnStart () <0x00103>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Fragging.MvxEventSourceFragmentActivity.OnStart () <0x00013>
at Android.App.Activity.n_OnStart (intptr,intptr) <0x00037>
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.ecfa86e9-900d-479e-9875-6960304e8202 (intptr,intptr) <0x0003b>
    at md526035c37b8d1573464bb4caa888f0f5d.MvxEventSourceFragmentActivity.n_onStart(Native Method)
    at md526035c37b8d1573464bb4caa888f0f5d.MvxEventSourceFragmentActivity.onStart(MvxEventSourceFragmentActivity.java:78)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1234)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6329)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
```

I'm familiar with stacktraces, but with this specific trace I can't figure out where to look for.

These errors occurres on various devices, 4.* and 5.*. I also tried to reproduce this error but didn't succeed.

Perhaps this is a specific Android thing that I can ignore?

Xamarin: 4.0.0.1717
Xamarin.Android: 6.0.0.35

**Edit 1**

I've found a [bugzilla item](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=35824). It shows somewhat the same issues. This item addresses Xamarin Forms. I don't use Xamarin Forms, but I've taken the steps to reproduce that error:

1. Start the app
2. Bring app to background
3. Stop process (using Android Device Manager)
4. Start app

And then I also get that error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.MyApp, PID: 4228
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at MyApp.Android.Views.Framents.MessageListFragment.OnCreateView (Android.Views.LayoutInflater inflater, Android.Views.ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x003a2] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_inflater, IntPtr native_container, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00022] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:85227a30-9274-46c5-a910-dd5907ec83c7 (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod) [0x00089] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Android.App.Activity.OnStart () [0x00079] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Fragging.MvxEventSourceFragmentActivity.OnStart () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnStart (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this) [0x00009] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:5c6d4542-2710-4e67-976d-a6e9d1ccd51c (intptr,intptr)
    at md526035c37b8d1573464bb4caa888f0f5d.MvxEventSourceFragmentActivity.n_onStart(Native Method)
    at md526035c37b8d1573464bb4caa888f0f5d.MvxEventSourceFragmentActivity.onStart(MvxEventSourceFragmentActivity.java:78)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this happening before. I would recommend using the `MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity` to let it handle activity lifecycle situations. You can find a sample of that here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples

Comment: Hoi Martijn, thanks for the quick response. I'm going to take a look at the MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity. I'll get back on this

Comment: Just noticed the tweet about Mvx 4.0 reaching stable. I immediately downloaded the examples. The project 'XPlatformMenus' is exactly what I needed.